# Is there any type of safe navigation operator for arithmetic in Groovy or Java?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

The following line of code is in one of my `if` statements:

```
$("#dateOfTransaction_month").val() != "${loadInstance?.payment?.dateOfTransaction?.getAt(Calendar.MONTH) + 1}"
```

Since Java's date/time management is such a mess I have to write `+ 1` to get the correct month.  The problem is that sometimes a `payment` object might not exist, so I would basically be saying `null + 1`.  This gives me the error `Cannot invoke method plus() on null object`.  Is there any neat way (neat being something like Groovy's [safe navigation operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator%28?.%29)) I can account for the possibility of a `payment` object being null in the `if` statement, or am I forced to check to see if the value is null before the `if` statement?

Comment: What would you consider the result of `month + 1` if `month` is `null`?

Comment: I would like the result to be null instead of an error. I think doelleri's answer does just that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Groovy adds a plus() method to Date which is what the + operator calls. You can directly call this yourself and chain a safe-navigation operator to it.

```
$("#dateOfTransaction_month").val() != "${loadInstance?.payment?.dateOfTransaction?.getAt(Calendar.MONTH)?.plus(1)}"
```

http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#plus(int)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that method, this is even better than the Elvis operator... very clean!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On that same page you have linked, actually right above, is the Elvis operator (some-maybe-null-value ?: default).
With the Elvis you can assign a default value you want to use.

e.g.

```
$("#dateOfTransaction_month").val() != "${(loadInstance?.payment?.dateOfTransaction?.getAt(Calendar.MONTH) ?: 0) + 1}"
```

Which would then default to being January

Comment: I had tried that operator, but wasn't using it right.  Seems to be working correctly now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue of working with the annoying Java Date and Calendar API's you might check out [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).  It's a dream to work with when compared to the built in API's.

Comment: I tried the JodaTime plugin for Grails and for some reason it was conflicting with the Spring Security Core plugin.  I didn't feel like hashing it out at the time so I just stuck with the Java/Groovy Date API.  Once I get more important things finished I may try the JodaTime plugin for Grails again.

Answer (score -1):

That is one thing i really like about Groovy when I played around with it, the ?. operator that automatically tested for null references.

There is no such thing in Java, you just have test whatever object hierarchy your are traversing to check for null values:

```
if (object1 != null && obecjt1.obecjt2 != null && object1.object2.object3 != null)
    do_something_awesome_with(object1.object2.object3);
```

However, your example is always going to cause trouble, because Groovy's ?. operator simply stops your traversal when it encounters a null reference and returns null.